# Need help to identify a sound effect/music

Tags: sound, music, effect

I hope you could help me, I'm trying to identify the name of the sound effect use at 5:07 in that video.

If anyone find it you'll get my eternal recognition. Thx for those who tried.

Answer (score 1):

So a bunch of people make sounds with their mouths, and the slap bass from Seinfield is layered underneath. I don't really know what else there is to say. I wouldn't even call it an effect, they just put a sample in. Most likely they have a pad with samples attached, and hit different buttons when they think it'll be the most funny.

Here's the bass (ignore the first second, which is a Beatles song for some reason)